# IIS 7 Cannot Create ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7

I have a web application that uses a local SQL Server Express database (a.k.a. ~/App_Data/ASPNETDB.MDF).

When I deploy to IIS 7.0 on Windows 2008 Standard (SP2), I get the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

The error message goes on to offer some advice

> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:
>
> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance
>   using a database location within the application's App_Data directory.
>   The provider attempted to automatically create the application
>   services database because the provider determined that the database
>   does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary
>   to successfully check for existence of the application services
>   database and automatically create the application services database:
>
> 1. If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server
>      2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to enable
>      automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information
>      is available at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If
>      the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web
>      server account must have read and write access to the application's
>      directory. This is necessary because the web server account will
>      automatically create the App_Data directory if it does not already
>      exist.
> 2. If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the web
>      server account only requires read and write access to the
>      application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because the web
>      server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Server Express
>      database already exists within the application's App_Data directory.
>      Revoking read access on the App_Data directory from the web server
>      account will prevent the provider from correctly determining if the
>      Sql Server Express database already exists. This will cause an error
>      when the provider attempts to create a duplicate of an already
>      existing database. Write access is required because the web server
>      account's credentials are used when creating the new database.
> 3. Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
> 4. The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a
>      local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.

I don't understand how to troubleshoot `4.` (where can I find the "readme document"?).  However, the other items look correct to me.

Specifically...

1. The app pool in question is running as NETWORK SERVICE (not Application Pool Identity)
2. The user NETWORK SERVICE has Full Control of App_Data (do I understand correctly that it does NOT need Read/Write for App_Data's parent, since App_Data is already created?)

Interestingly, if I **copy** ASPNETDB.MDF and ASPNETDB.LDF from my development machine to the production App_Data, the error changes:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the relevant tables to a new SQL Server database because I could not resolve the permissions issue.

That is the recommended approach anyhow for a production application, though it seems unfortunate that it was so hard (in terms of determining how to configure security) to deploy the ASPNETDB.MDF variant for a very low-volume website.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before and the problem was that my SQL Server service was stopped, this is pretty weird but sometimes they just crash,I had to reinstall SQL Server cause the service didn't even alloud me to start it,so you may want to check this.

Comment: Good point, but not the case for me.  The service is running and I can also attach the .MDB file that I copied over from my dev machine in SSMS.